# How is Python 2.7 suddenly a Windows security threat?

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, antivirus

I have a `python 2.7` anaconda environment (I can't upgrade it to python 3 yet, I hope python2 isn't suddenly viewed a security threat). This python was working fine last week. This morning I come in and try to run some python code in it (that I haven't run before, but came from a contractor of ours).

When I ran it I noticed that (I don't think it was a coincidence) Windows suddenly reported a threat:
[image]

and now when I run python, I get:

```
$ python
bash: /home/username/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

and when I try to disable the quarantine from Windows Security, I still get that same error.

I'm using Ubuntu Windows Subsystem Linux. I've never seen an error like this before.

Does anybody know what might be causing this problem (or how to recover without rebuilding my environment, assuming that would work)?

Update: I deleted that environment, upgraded Anaconda, and rebuilt my environment (python 2.7) from scratch. It appears to be working again, including what I'd tried before that might have triggered the problem.

I also noticed that my "Virus & threat protection updates" had updated itself 30 minutes before this problem started (at 8:23), and it has since updated again (at 9:45). So perhaps some errant security definition?

Comment: The only obvious thing is 2.7 had end of life last week. It might be considered a threat because it's no longer updated, so it's a vulnerability?

Comment: Did you check the checksums when you downloaded it?

Comment: I downloaded this > 1 yr ago and just never updated

Comment: And, this was working last week (which was also after eof)

Comment: Windows might consider it a security vulnerability. That is if it gets no updates for years somebody might exploit it and find a weakness to access your system. It is not really a theat. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Support for Python 2.* ended starting with 2020 (EOL)

Comment: I thought that would just mean that it wasn't getting additional support... not that existing features are all of the sudden "Severe" threats.

Comment: Yeah exactly. No support means no updates. This is considered unsafe.

Comment: according to https://www.anaconda.com/end-of-life-eol-for-python-2-7-is-coming-are-you-ready/
"Just because 2.7 isn’t going to be maintained past 2020 doesn’t mean your applications or libraries suddenly stop working."

Comment: That’s right, they don’t. But since Windows also acts as antivirus (defender), it flags python 2.*. You can still run it tho

Answer (score 0):

Using any EOL software is risky, because they no longer receive security updates. Complex software like programming languages often have many unknown and therefore unresolved issues. To compound this programming language runtimes, like the python2 interpreter, often accept data from unpredictable sources like the Internet.

Consider the hypothetical: If there is an unknown issue in networking code that allows "arbitrary execution of remote code" there is no infrastructure to inform you about it or to fix it. When malicious actors find it you will have problems.

It is rarely that simple, often a security violation requires exploiting multiple issues.

Consider this Python2 CVE list: https://www.activestate.com/products/python/python-2-end-of-life-security-updates/

There are a few issues in python2 itself that doom a project, some might think they are safe if they avoid hosting a web server. If you use a library to parse URIs, handle complex XML, or do image manipulation and get that date from the internet then you would need to know about and fix or workaround issues that can potentially allow malicious actors to do things on or to your systems.

All of these issues existed when python was EOLed in 2020. They all still exist now. It is prudent to presume more exist.